# Jest unit testing arguments of each instance of function when called multiple times, but with slightly different outcomes

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing

I am calling a function that logs out, multiple times in one of my functions, and I am wanting to test the args passed each time it logs out.

I did have this working, but have since changed how what it is passing slightly.

Originally I was logging a string and then an object, ie.

```
myObject = {
  'one': 'one',
  'two': 'two'
}

myfunct() {
  log.info('some string', myObject);
  log.info('some other string', myObject);
}
```

and I was testing with

```
// spying on logger
...
expect(spyLog).toHaveBeenNthCalledWith(1, 'some string', myObject);
expect(spyLog).toHaveBeenNthCalledWith(2, 'some other string', myObject);
```

I have now changed the object to actually incorporate the string that will be assigned directly, ie:

```
myNewObject(myString: string) {
  return {
    'string': myString,
    'one': 'one',
    'two': 'two'
  }
}

myfunct() {
  log.info(myNewObject('some string'));
  log.info(myNewObject('some other string'));
}
```

Is there a way in which I can test the passed arguments without having to create consts of each differing object?

ie. I am wanting to avoid a situation such as:

```
myFirstObject = {
  'string': 'some string',
  'one': 'one',
  'two': 'two'
};

mySecondObject = {
  'string': 'some other string',
  'one': 'one',
  'two': 'two'
};

expect(spyLog).toHaveBeenNthCalledWith(1, myFirstObject);
expect(spyLog).toHaveBeenNthCalledWith(2, mySecondObject);
```

If I have more of these logs outputting, I do not wish to have mountains of consts defining almost identical information...